# Why does BeautifulSoup work the second time parsing, but not the first

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is the `ResultSet` of running `soup[0].find_all('div', {'class':'font-160 line-110'})`:

```
[<div class="font-160 line-110" data-container=".snippet-container" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-template='&lt;div class="tooltip infowin-tooltip" role="tooltip"&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-arrow"&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-arrow-inner"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-inner" style="text-align: left"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;' data-toggle="tooltip" title="XIAMEN [CN]">    
    <a class="no-underline group-ib color-inherit"
    href="/en/ais/details/ports/959">
    <span class="text-default">CN</span><span class="text-default text-darker">XMN
</span>
</a>
</div>]
```

In an attempt to pull out `XIAMEN [CN]` after `title` I could not use `a[0].find('div')['title]` (where `a` is the above `BeautifulSoup ResultSet`). However, if I copy and paste that HTML as a new string, say,

```
b = '''<div class="font-160 line-110" data-container=".snippet container" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-template='&lt;div class="tooltip infowin-tooltip" role="tooltip"&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-arrow"&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-arrow-inner"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-inner" style="text-align: left"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;' data-toggle="tooltip" title="XIAMEN [CN]">'''
```

Then do:

```
>>soup = BeautifulSoup(b, 'html.parser')
>>soup.find('div')['title']
>>XIAMEN [CN] #prints contents of title
```

Why do I have to reSoup the Soup? Why doesn't this work on my first search?

Edit, origin of `soup`:

I have a list of `urls` that I'm going though via `grequests`. One of the things I'm looking for is that `title` that contains `XIAMEN [CN]`.

So `soup` was created when I did

```
soup = []
    with i in range(2) #number of pages parsed
     rawSoup = BeautifulSoup(response[i].content, 'html.parser')   
     souporigin = rawSoup.find_all('div', {'class': 'bg-default bg-white no-    snippet-hide'})
    soup.append(souporigin)
```

The urls are

```
[
'http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:564352/imo:9643752/mmsi:511228000/vessel:DE%20MI',
'http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:3780155/imo:9712395/mmsi:477588800/vessel:SITC%20GUANGXI?cb=2267'
]
```

Comment: What are you doing with `soup[0]` and what is it? Pretty sure you are doing two completely different things.

Comment: `soup` is a list of `ResultSet`s, I'm using `soup[0]` to access the first entry of that list.

Comment: Can you add the html or a link to the page as I am pretty confident you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Which url has the title?

Comment: They both do. In the first one title is `MAANSHAN [CN]` and in the second one it's `XIAMEN [CN]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125460/discussion-between-rafael-martins-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: Rafael, you should add your answer summarising what we discussed in chat and accept it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem occurred when I set up my BeautifulSoup. I created a list of partial search results then had to iterate over the list to research it. I fixed this by just searching for what I wanted in on line:

I changed:

```
soup = []
    with i in range(2) #number of pages parsed
     rawSoup = BeautifulSoup(response[i].content, 'html.parser')   
     souporigin = rawSoup.find_all('div', {'class': 'bg-default bg-white no-    snippet-hide'})
     soup.append(souporigin)
```

to:

```
 a = soup.find("div", class_='font-160 line-110')["title"]
```

And run this search as soon as I create my `soup` which removes a lot of redundancies in the code-- I had been creating lists of `ResultSets` and having to use `find` on them for new fields.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong selection.

Selection `soup[0].find_all('div', {'class':'font-160 line-110'})` finds `<div>` and you can even see `<div>` when you print it. But when you add `.find()` it starts searching **inside** `<div>` - so `.find('div')` tries to find new `div` in current `div`

You need

```
a[0]['title']
```

---

When you create new soup then main/root element is not `div` but `[document]` and `div` is its child (`div` is inside main "tag") so you can use `find('div')`.

```
>>> a[0].name
div

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(b, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.name
[document]
```